# Ignoring HTTP response for web service one-way operation

Tags: java, web-services, jax-ws

I am developing a jax-ws webservice that pushes messages asynchronously to the subscribed consumers using one-way operation.

Unfortunatelly with each notification, server awaits a HTTP202 response confirmation which blocks the thread for a fraction of a second. This is affecting the performance of the system and I am looking for a way around this.

Is there any way to execute a web-service one-way call and ignore the HTTP response status?

Comment: What client are you using ?

Comment: Custom jax-ws based webservice

Comment: How about firing the each request in a new thread, that way your container thread will become free immediately.

Comment: Each request is already in a new thread, but those threads still wait for the client response and the number of processors is limited. I need to be able to send hundreds of notifications per second, and right now with 2 cores I can only achieve about 5 per second cause the threads get stuck for a fraction of a second until the response comes back.

Comment: Threads are in wait state, they shouldn't affect your CPU consumption. Meaning CPU is ready to receive another Thread.

Comment: Hmm, im using a ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor and scheduleAtFixedRate (rate, not delay) to schedule each message as a separate runnable.
In the logs I can see that some Notify is launched then 0.3 second break occurs and I get log "Notify done" from the same thread. Imidiately later another Notify is launched.
In the wireshark its the same, Notify, 0.3s break -> Http202, then imidiately later another Notify

Comment: If you really need it then you may try to send plain HTTP packet using socket.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, so after spending a lot of time on this I have found two solutions:

1) Using Apache HTTPComponents, which provide AsyncHTTPClient with nice API allowing us to build a HTTP response from the scratch.

2) More web-service oriented solution based on Apache CXF platform (which includes the HTTPClient implementation) - first we need to set the global Bus property:

```
Bus bus = BusFactory.getDefaultBus();
bus.setProperty(AsyncHTTPConduit.USE_ASYNC, Boolean.TRUE);
```

Then, we use custom interceptor to set the message exchange property to asynchronous:

```
final class SkipWaitInterceptor extends AbstractSoapInterceptor {

    SkipWaitInterceptor() {
        super(Phase.SETUP);
    }

    @Override
    public void handleMessage(final SoapMessage message) throws Fault {
        message.getExchange().setSynchronous(false);
    }

}
```

Finally, we register the interceptor on our asynchronous Endpoint

```
org.apache.cxf.endpoint.Client client =
                org.apache.cxf.frontend.ClientProxy.getClient(this.notificationConsumer);
org.apache.cxf.endpoint.Endpoint cxfEndpoint = client.getEndpoint();
cxfEndpoint.getOutInterceptors().add(new SkipWaitInterceptor());
```

That's all, one-way operation responses no longer block the communication.